# Android horizontal scrolling tabs in menubar

Tags: android

I am looking at making a navbar like this in android: 
[Scketch of navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsRSO.png)

Everything is straight forward beside the months.
I want to be able to scroll through the months by dragging or by clicking a month.
I also want the current month to be the one centered on start.

Any suggestions on how to make this is welcome.

Comment: You may use a horizontal scoll view filled with image views representing the months. Below that you could then place your tab view.

Comment: http://blog.grafixartist.com/parallax-scrolling-tabs-design-support-library/

Comment: Use TabLayout with app:tabMode=”scrollable”. You'll find the implementation and code under the topic Scrollable Tabs [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/).

Comment: FragmentStatePagerAdapter take a look a this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coverted the above comment as answer. Hope it solves your problem.

Use TabLayout with **app:tabMode=”scrollable”**. You'll find the implementation and code under the topic **Scrollable Tabs** [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/).

Answer (score -1):

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

make Horizontal scrollview in custom layout.